# how to read and write Android myself contact

Tags: android, contacts

I am working with Android contacts, which is Android 4.0.3. In the contact app, I can create, add, edit and see myself contact in it. But when I tried to get myself contact from my app using contentResolver, it did not work. How can I read and write myself contact?
Thanks in advance.

EDIT: here is my code to get contacts

List list = new ArrayList();

```
    Uri uri = Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
    String[] projection = new String[] {
            Contacts._ID,
            Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY,
            Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
            Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER,
            Contacts.PHOTO_ID,
            Contacts.LAST_TIME_CONTACTED,
            Contacts.TIMES_CONTACTED
    };

    String sortOrder = Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";  
    if (sortColumn != null) {
        if (sortColumn.equals(Contacts.LAST_TIME_CONTACTED) || sortColumn.equals(Contacts.TIMES_CONTACTED))
            sortOrder = "" + sortColumn  + " COLLATE LOCALIZED DESC";
    }

    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, sortOrder);

        while (cursor.moveToNext()){
            list.add(getRecord(context, cursor));
        }

        return list;
    } finally {
        if (cursor!=null) cursor.close();
    }
```

Comment: can you paste your code so that i can see why it didn't work?

Comment: I have found a clue. Android ContactsContract.Contacts class has a field IS_USER_PROFILE, which represents the user's personal profile entry. I will try this and then if I have good result, I will add comment.

Comment: I am looking into ContactsContract.Profile class.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Uri below.

```
Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(
ContactsContract.Profile.CONTENT_URI,
ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
```

This is the path of "Myself".